# Is there any situation QueryString is present but HttpServletRequest.getParameterMap() is empty?

Tags: spring-boot, servlets, tomcat9

I have encouterd an odd situation while we are doing press testing in our test env. When the app load is high, the Query String will missing occasionally and the Spring will throw `MissingServletRequestParameterException`.
In order to find the root cause , I add some logs at the foremost `Filter`(code is shown below), and something weired happened.

```
    public static void printRequestParameter(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = request.getParameterMap();
        log.info("Request URI : {}, method = {} , query string = {}", request.getRequestURI(), request.getMethod(), request.getQueryString());
        if (MapUtils.isNotEmpty(parameterMap)) {
            parameterMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
                log.info("Request parameter name = {}, value = {}", k, ArrayUtils.isEmpty(v) ? Strings.EMPTY : Arrays.stream(v).collect(Collectors.joining(COMMA)));
            });
        }
    }
```

The `request.getParameterMap()` is empty, but , the  query string is not empty , and I got a log like :

```
Request URI : /a/b/c, method = POST , query string = foo=bar.
```

But no logs like:

```
Request parameter name = foo , value = bar
```

And our `Controller` use `@RequestParam() String foo` to receivce the parameter , finally , the Spring throws

```
MissingServletRequestParameterException Handler org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'foo' is not present
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableH
```

I just wonder, why the parameter in query string is not contained in `parameterMap`?
Note:
**The odd behavior is only happened occasionally, at most time it's just works.**
My spring boot version is `2.3.9.RELEASE` and the embedded tomcat version is `9.0.43`.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide some examples of query strings for which parameter parsing fails?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I think I'm encountering a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73629092/missingservletrequestparameterexception-intermittently-being-thrown-even-though

Comment: @JamesPizzurro you figured out the issue ?
I am facing similar issue

Comment: @SudhirN Yes I did! Here's what worked for me along with some background: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73631328/1072621

Comment: Finally, it's @Async issue

Answer (score 2):

Since the specification does not allow [`ServletRequest.getParameterMap`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/servletrequest#getParameterMap--) to throw any exception, any failure in parameter parsing will cause the parameter list to be empty.

To detect this situation you can log the [`"org.apache.catalina.parameter_parse_failed_reason"`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/constant-values.html#org.apache.catalina.Globals.PARAMETER_PARSE_FAILED_REASON_ATTR) attribute of your request.

Examples of query strings that should fail:

- `?=noname`,
- `?urlEncoding=%ue`

Answer (score 1):

Finally, It's `@Async` issue , some guy put this annotation on the Controller class